# How to get code to correctly count items (a variable) from one spreadsheet and successfully display this information?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need my VBA code to count all the "x's" on a certain spreadsheet(pc) and then transfer this information to a report (rp) I am creating to display all the individuals choices. At the moment the code identifies all the ID on the sheet but however only acknowledges the first 4 options for each individual, where as some have much more than this. Throughout the course of this code I have made edits to options from Column K to Y and I assume this is the reason why the code is only acknowledging the options that haven't been altered. I have made adaptions to the code but have no idea how to correct this so that all options are successfully displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Specific Spreadsheet Code will Read from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQDvk.png)

[Code Report Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2csAh.png)

```
rp.Cells(1, 1) = "Modules"
rp.Cells(1, 2) = "Student Count"
rp.Cells(1, 4) = "Students registered"
rp.Cells(1, 10) = "Students registered2"   'new

nRow = 2
For c = 2 To pc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    rp.Cells(nRow, 1) = pc.Cells(1, c)
    rp.Cells(nRow, 2) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(pc.Columns(c), "x")
    nRow = nRow + 1
Next c
      

rp.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
If rp.Cells(2, 4).Text <> "" Then
    rp.Cells(1, 4).CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End If
rp.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
rp.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: Code writing to report columns D:F is not included in the snippet you publish. Therefore it's not possible to determine why it writes to only 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code snippet is not sufficient to determine the cause of your problem you would definitely gain by not interacting with the sheet when manipulating data. consider the example hereunder as an alternative approach:

```
Option Explicit
Sub consolidate()
    Dim arr, arrH
    With Sheet1
        arr = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Value2 'get all data in memory
        arrH = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(arr, 2))).Value2 'get the header in an array
    End With
    
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, ii As Long: ii = 1
    Dim arrC: ReDim arrC(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrH, 2)) '=> setup counter array
    Dim arr2: ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2)) '=> setup new array to modify source data
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr) 'traverse rows
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2) 'traverse columns
            'here we can access each cell by referencing our array(<rowCounter>, <columnCounter>
            'e.g. arr(j,i) => if j = 1 and i = 1 we'll have the values of Cell A1
            'we can dump these values anywhere in the activesheet, other sheet, other workbook, ..
            'but to limit the number of interactions with our sheet object we can also use an intermediant arrays
            If arr(j, i) <> "" Then 'check if x
                arr2(j, ii) = arrH(1, i) 'replace x with the value from the header
                arr2(j, 1) = arr(j, 1) 'force the value in col1
                ii = ii + 1 'increment consolidated counter
                    
                arrC(1, i) = arrC(1, i) + 1 'increment sum
            End If
        Next i
        ii = 1 'reset consolidated counter for next line
    Next j
    'when we are ready with our data we dumb to the sheet
    With Sheet2 'the with allows us the re-use the sheet name without typing it again
        'the ubound function allows us to size the "range" to the same size as our array, once that's done we can just dumb it to the sheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arrH, 2), 1)).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrH) 'transpose to get the col's in rows
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(arrC, 2), 2)).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrC)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(UBound(arr2), UBound(arr2, 2) + 3)).Value2 = arr2
    End With
End Sub
```